# ¿How to use a serializer for @record.all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a `Kit` model with it's serializer:

```
class KitSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description
  has_many :products, only: [:id, :price]
end
```

I need to use this serializer to render all of my Kits like this:

```
  def kits_json
    @kits = Kit.all
    render json: @kits, serializer: KitSerializer
  end
```

My route

```
get '/api/kits', to: 'kits#kits_json'
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Kit::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class
```

It's my first time with serializers, what am I missing?

Comment: Since `@kits` is array of objects, you should use `each_serializer` instead `serializer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `@kits` is an array of objects, you should use `each_serializer` instead of `serializer`

your controller will look like as:

```
def kits_json
  @kits = Kit.all
  render json: @kits, each_serializer: KitSerializer
end
```

If you wanna pass render array of json you can use it as below:

```
def kits_json
  @kits = Kit.all
  render json: [ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@kits, serializer: KitSerializer)]
end
```

Comment: How can you apply this to an array of render json? Can't get it to work with parenthesis (Will only work if I only render 1 thing)

render json: [
            products: (products, each_serializer: ProductSerializer, root: false),
            boxes: boxes,
          ]

Comment: can you try this once `[ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(products, serializer: ProductSerializer)]`

Comment: @AmolMohite probably should add that to the answer as it has value specific to the posed question